# Checking that all items in a collection match a predicate in Scala

Tags: scala, predicate

What's the most idiomatic way to test whether all items of a collection match a predicate?

Any item?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

There are built-in functions for this:

```
List(1,2,3,4).forall(x => x < 5)
res0: Boolean = true
```

for any:

```
List(1,2,3,4).exists(x => x > 3)
res1: Boolean = true
```